# I have changed the host url in IIS, do I need to change the Topology Manager baseurl also

Tags: web8, topology-manager

I have changed the hosturl (or domain name) in IIS for one of the websites. Do I need to change the baseurl in Topology Manager as well?

Whether the publishing will still work? Or I need to change the baseurl as well in Topology Manger for that particular mapping. Please suggest me?

Answer (score 2):

**Question:** I have changed the hosturl (or domain name) in IIS for one of the websites. Do I need to change the baseurl in Topology Manager as well?

**Answers:** Yes. Update the BaseURL in Topology manager for that website

Eg:

> Set-TtmWebsite -Id Staging_Website -Baseurls
>   @("https://new-domain-host")

**Question:** Whether the publishing will still work?

**Answers:** Yes. Publishing no impact since you only changed the web app URL host-name.

Answer (score 1):

The base url need to map to the url that customer will use to browse to the website. Without it publishing will still work, but, url to publication resolving in Content Delivery would not work. This would lead to issues with XPM not working as expected, if your application is something like DxA it is not going to work, view on sites is not going to work and more...